# Qr scanning app is crashing when device orientation is changed

Tags: java, android

I made a basic qr code scanner in android, but it is crashing after rotating the device to landscape and then again to portrait mode while scanning qr code.
Please also briefly explain what is causing the problem. Do i need to release some resource. P.S i am a beginner.

```
package com.example.android.qrking;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v7.app.AlertDialog;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.View;
import com.google.zxing.Result;
import me.dm7.barcodescanner.zxing.ZXingScannerView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements ZXingScannerView.ResultHandler{
    private  ZXingScannerView mScannerView;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    }

    public void onClick(View v){
        mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);
        setContentView(mScannerView);
        mScannerView.setResultHandler(this);
        mScannerView.startCamera();
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        mScannerView.stopCamera();
    }

    @Override
    public void handleResult(Result result){
        Log.v("handler result", result.getText());
        AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
        builder.setTitle("scan results");
        builder.setMessage(result.getText());
        AlertDialog alertDialog = builder.create();
        alertDialog.show();
        //uncomment to scan again
        mScannerView.resumeCameraPreview(this);
    }
}
```

Logcat details

```
03-09 21:18:24.460 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x419bac98)
03-09 21:18:24.461 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: uncaught exception occurred
03-09 21:18:24.461 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err: java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.android.qrking/com.example.android.qrking.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 21:18:24.464 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
03-09 21:18:24.464 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3193)
03-09 21:18:24.464 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3899)
03-09 21:18:24.464 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
03-09 21:18:24.464 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
03-09 21:18:24.464 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
03-09 21:18:24.465 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err: Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
03-09 21:18:24.466 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at com.example.android.qrking.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:29)
03-09 21:18:24.466 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5368)
03-09 21:18:24.466 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1239)
03-09 21:18:24.466 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3224)
03-09 21:18:24.466 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/System.err:     ... 12 more
03-09 21:18:24.466 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking W/dalvikvm: threadid=1: calling UncaughtExceptionHandler
03-09 21:18:24.469 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.android.qrking, PID: 10365
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to pause activity {com.example.android.qrking/com.example.android.qrking.MainActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3242)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3899)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151)
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640)
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.example.android.qrking.MainActivity.onPause(MainActivity.java:29)
    at android.app.Activity.performPause(Activity.java:5368)
    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnPause(Instrumentation.java:1239)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3224)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.performPauseActivity(ActivityThread.java:3193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleRelaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:3899) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$900(ActivityThread.java:151) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1327) 
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:110) 
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:193) 
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5292) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method) 
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:515) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:824) 
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:640) 
    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method) 
03-09 21:18:30.246 10365-10365/com.example.android.qrking I/Process: Sending signal. PID: 10365 SIG: 9
```

Comment: Post the Logcat errors that are printed when the app crashes

Comment: this is the log cat error:-

Comment: move `mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);` inside `onCreate`

Comment: putting mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this); inside onCreate solved the crashing. sir, can you explain how did it work? thanks. @PavneetSingh

Answer (score 1):

By default when changing the orientation your activity will restart, which is probably causing the crash.

Add this in your manifest.xml file:

```
    android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"
```

To stop the activity restarting each time.

Comment: adding android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize" to manifest prevents the app from crashing but the window size is decreased each time  i rotate the device.

Answer (score 1):

Initially screen is in `portrait` mode

**Step 1** : click the button , initialize the `mScannerView` object

**Step 2** : rotate phone horizontally , as per [`Activity-lifecycle`](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle.html) you have `overridden` `onPause()` so camera will `stopped` using `stopCamera()` and your `portrait` activity will be destroyed and **now your newly created `horizontal activity` will have `mScannerView` as `null`**

**Step 3** : Rotate the device again to `portrait` mode

Now at this time your `horizontal` activity go inside `onPause` state again and `mScannerView` object is `null` so `mScannerView.stopCamera()` will cause exception for invoking a function on `null` object  hence the crash

so the solution initialize your views inside `onCreate` , because `onCreate` will be executed once your activity is recreated

**solution** : move `mScannerView = new ZXingScannerView(this);` inside `onCreate`